# How to use Craco to add instructions to Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, craco

I would like to add these instructions to Webpack through [Craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#installation):

```
{
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: false,
          publicPath: 'assets'
        },
        type:'javascript/auto'
      }
```

How to do this?
I'm not familiar with Webpack or Craco at all

Basically what I'm trying to do is that I have animals.json file but currently when importing it via:

import animals from './animals.json'

I end up with the contents of the json file when I actually want a URL like localhost:8000/static/media/animals.json  and only when I open that link should the contents of the json file be displayed...

I have been instructed that overriding webpack's default functionality via the above lines can accomplish this...